# jquery not showing up in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am pulling info from an XML file and the `div class="long"` works great but the anchor doesn't work or doesn't show up in IE.  It works in all other browsers but NOT IE?  any thoughts?

```
$(this).find('desc').each(function() 
{
    var url = $(this).find('url').text();
    var long = $(this).find('long').text();

    $('<div class="long"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id);
    $('<a href="http://'+url+'"</a>').html(url).appendTo('#link_'+id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('<a href="http://'+url+'"></a>').html(url).appendTo('#link_'+id);` ?

You left the closing bracket of your `a` tag open.

Comment: I wish that was it.. i have it closed further down in my code.

Comment: Did you try doing it in one step: `$('#link_'+id).append('<a href="http://'+url+'">'+url+'</a>');`

What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Xtian - Can you clarify?  You can't be closing it further down in your code, that's a node/document fragment creation, you need to create a value node at that point.

Comment: Aaron, doing it in one step worked!  I am using IE 7 and it shows up using your code.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, on a (slightly self-serving) side note, as @matt suggested, you should accept answers if they are correct.